# how do you split up or join a linq query on an "or" (without using Union)?

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

Suppose you're searching some object with two boolean properties, A and B.

What if you have two linq queries:

```
IQueryable<ObjectType> query = getIQueryableSomehow()
query.Where(x => x.A);

IQueryable<ObjectType> query2 = getIQueryableSomehow()
query2.Where(x => x.B);
```

How can I join these queries together so that they are equivalent to this?:

```
IQueryable<ObjectType> query3 = getIQueryableSomehow()
query3.Where(x => x.A || x.B)
```

I would like to use query3 = query.Union(query2), but sadly in my Linq provider union is not supported.

I split up the case for x => x.A && x.B by chaining the where clause. This is what I mean:

```
IQueryable<ObjectType> query = getIQueryableSomehow();
query = query.Where(x => x.A);
query = query.Where(x => x.B);
```

Is there some similar workaround for the or case?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

```
IQueryable<ObjectType> query = getIQueryableSomehow();
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ObjectType>();
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.A);
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.B);

var list = query.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. I'll try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Works great. I'm in your debt Adrian!

Answer (score 1):

If your LINQ provider doesn't support the Union operator, you can always first materialize the query results using ToArray(), and then use the LINQ-to-objects provider to perform the union, which it supports, like so:

```
IQueryable<ObjectType> query = getIQueryableSomehow() 
query.Where(x => x.A); 

IQueryable<ObjectType> query2 = getIQueryableSomehow() 
query2.Where(x => x.B); 

IQueryable<ObjectType> query3 = query.ToArray().AsQueryable<ObjectType>().Union(query2);
```

This will work well as long as your results being unioned are not too large.

Comment: I prefer not to do this, I want to retrieve as few records from the database as possible. I know that will work though! Thanks.